# Linq expression, get parameters?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I got a linq expression,

```
internal T Execute<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, string, T>> expr)
{
    var paramInt = ??;
    var paramString = ??;
}
```

I call this method using this:

```
Expression<Func<int, string, Guid>> myExpression2 = (a,b) => Callmethod(a, b, 5);

Execute<Guid>(myExpression2);
```

How can i get the parameters from the expression in my execute method ?

-- To clarify --

I want to get the values from the parameters so that i do some calculations with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can get the parameters using the [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.parameters.aspx) property.

```
var parameters = expr.Parameters;
```

However, each of those will be a `ParameterExpression`. That will give you the parameter name and the type, but it's not clear what you want to do with them.

Comment: I want to get the values from the parameters so that i do some calculations with them.

Comment: @Patrick: The parameters don't *have* values - they're *parameters*. It's like asking what the value of a method parameter is - it only has a value when it's invoked.

Comment: @Jon, I think he want to extract the values passed within the expression.

Comment: @Filip: But which values in this case? The only value we've got is 5, which is the argument for the method call *within* the expression tree...

Comment: @Jon, Right, but when they are invoked they must have a value, no? So that value is the one you want to extract. The 5 for instance, would that be possible to extract?

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please shed some light into this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/17796800/114029